# Change positioning of two bootstrap rows depending on the button you click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two bootstrap rows on my page and two buttons that appear on the top of the screen. I want, when the second button is clicked, then the second row comes on top of the first row and vice versa.
Those are my two rows

```
<div class="row mothers_day-row mothers_day-row-share">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
           Text
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row mothers_day-row mothers_day-row-create">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
          Text 2
    </div>
</div>
```

And my buttons will be something like this

```
 <button class="regular mothers_day_first_button" id="mothers_day1">First row on top</button>

 <button class="regular mothers_day_second_button" id="mothers_day2">Second row on top</button>
```

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: so, you need move to top div with text 2 if clic in second. You can create a father div and use append and prepend to move second div.

Comment: @Paulie_D you are right, i am a junior web developer and I am not that good at javascript. I believe this is a complex task to achieve, that's why I asked the question that way. Also I conducted a lot of research before posting, but I couldn't find something worthy of adding at my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is to add `data-*` attributes to your buttons to tell them which div to push on top. Then on click of the buttons, take the div as set in its `data-target-div` property make a clone of it and remove it from the DOM. Now add the cloned `div` into your main div by using `prepend`

```js
$(function(){
  $('button.regular').on('click',function(){
     var $div = $($(this).data('target-div'));
     var clonedDiv = $div.clone();
     $div.remove();
     $('#mainDiv').prepend(clonedDiv);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainDiv">
<div id="firstDiv" class="row mothers_day-row mothers_day-row-share">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
           Text 1
    </div>
</div>

<div id="secondDiv" class="row mothers_day-row mothers_day-row-create">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
          Text 2
    </div>
</div>
</div>


 <button class="regular mothers_day_first_button" id="mothers_day1" data-target-div="#firstDiv">First row on top</button>

 <button class="regular mothers_day_second_button" id="mothers_day2" data-target-div="#secondDiv">Second row on top</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, very quick and very detailed answer!

Comment: I know this is the accepted answer but... the solution is not exactly changing the position of divs... you are cut copy and pasting the divs...

Comment: @RRR I agree, But I don't think positioning the div's using CSS will be efficient as you have no idea on how complex the div's might get (its not here in the example), Like you might end up having child nodes with what ever CSS.. So I thought this would be right... Correct me If I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hi since in your question you have asked `Change position` I am posting this answer: kindly check demo https://jsfiddle.net/7a4pqL1r/1/

**HTML**

```
<button class="regular mothers_day_first_button" id="mothers_day1">First row on top</button>

 <button class="regular mothers_day_second_button" id="mothers_day2">Second row on top</button>

<div class="row mothers_day-row mothers_day-row-share">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
           ROW1
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row mothers_day-row mothers_day-row-create">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
          ROW2
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mothers_day-row-share , .mothers_day-row-create{
    height:100px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid grey;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
    color:#fff;

  }
 .mothers_day-row-share {
   background:red;
 } 

 .mothers_day-row-create {
   background:blue;
 }
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mothers_day_second_button').on('click', function(){
  console.log('hi');
    $('.mothers_day-row-share').animate({top: "110px"}); 
    $('.mothers_day-row-create').animate({top: "-110px"});
  });

  $('.mothers_day_first_button').on('click', function(){
  console.log('hi');
    $('.mothers_day-row-create').animate({top: "0px"}); 
    $('.mothers_day-row-share').animate({top: "0px"});
  });
});
```

Comment: the problem is that i don't want to set the height of my rows because of responsiveness and that the elements of the rows will change dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can quite simply use the `Element: before()` method.

```
var row0 = document.getElementsByClassName('row')[0]
var row1 = document.getElementsByClassName('row')[1]

row1.before(row0);
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/before